# Postgres - join tables based on a variable

Tags: postgresql

If I create a query with SQLAlchemy or string formatted variables and then read the .sql file with Python, I am able to accomplish exactly what I am looking for. My query will only read the specific partitions that I am trying to work with.

```
SELECT a, b, c, ..., FROM fact_'{date}' 

LEFT JOIN dimension_a_'{date}' 

LEFT JOIN dimension_b_'{date}'
```

Is there a way to pass a variable directly into a Postgres query or view? These tables are partitioned daily and I would run out of shared memory if I tried to blindly join the master tables, even if I specify a date.

I am hoping for a way to say

```
SELECT * FROM view WHERE report_date = '2018-01-02'
```

And have that 2018-01-02 be added to the table names, so I only look at and attempt to join specific partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer a possible solution below, but consider that this is almost certainly not the route you want to take.  The problem you're working around has already been elegantly and efficiently solved at the DB level through *partitioning*.  Consider thoroughly reading [Postgresql's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Meanwhile, to respond to the question as posed, note that having a dynamic table name that the DB server interpolates for you is not implemented in any database of which I'm aware: you will need to send a fresh query to the DB engine each time.  (Given some knowledge of DB theory in general, this actually makes some sense, but that's outside the scope of this response.)  One possible workaround would be to dynamically create VIEWs, and then query those:

```
SELECT * FROM view_2018_01_02;
```

Not ideal, and still requires interpolation at a level above the DB, but an option.

A more direct answer to your question might use a DB function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trench_report_date_func(rdate TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE(a AS ..., b AS ...)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ... FROM '
      || 'fact_' || rdate
      || ' LEFT JOIN dimension_a_' || rdate
      || ' LEFT JOIN dimension_b_' || rdate;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that this indeed follows as stated above and sends a *fresh query to the DB engine* every time.  You might call it as:

```
SELECT * FROM trench_report_date_func(...);
```

Again, you can ham-fist a solution around this approach, but I urge you to consider proper partitioning.  You have wisely chosen Postgres; now use its robustness to your advantage!

Comment: When building dynamic SQL, `format()` is usually easier to use

Comment: Ooh!  I didn't realize we had `printf`-like capabilities now.  Since September 2012, and all supported PG versions.  Nice!

Comment: Hi - to be clear, I am using Postgres 10 with the built in partitioning. The issue is that my fact data (daily partitioned, ~2 million rows per day), is being joined to a daily partitioned snapshot of employee data (50,000+ rows per day). The partitions go back to 2014, so if I just try to join them I run out of shared memory (max_locks_per_transaction). If I query directly for a specific date, it is incredibly fast though.

Comment: @trench okay, then the function route I propose above is likely your best bet, given the constraints provided.